# How to correct a weird bash prompt on a Debian (Squeeze) server?

Tags: shell, debian, profile

I have never had to deal much with BASH setup under Debian Linux, but this time, somebody has given me a server that acts weird.

When I log on as root, everything works as I am used to: I see a normal prompt telling me who/where I am, pressing the UP key displays previously typed commands, etc.

But when I log on as a created user, the prompt is "$", the UP key displays the characters ^[[A and when I try to change the prompt by typing PS1="\u@\h:\w\$ " the prompt literally becomes \u@\h:\w\$ - i.e. \u is not replaced by user name, etc.

Looking at the etc/profile and the etc/bash.bashrc files does not give me any clues. And I have I tried Google'ing to no avail.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? A step-by-step guide to which files to look at and what they should could be helpful. Another approach could be to reset a user's bash settings (without having to delete and restore the user).

Comment: The user's login shell is apparently `/bin/sh`, or at least not Bash.  Try `man chsh` or as a quick workaround `exec /bin/bash -login`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `finger username` ... it's likely the system has a different default shell. If the shell line doesn't say `/bin/bash` you can change it with

`usermod -s /bin/bash username`

EDIT: forgot to mention, if the user is logged in. Log them out and back in after you do that command.

Comment: Very basic, I know, but nevertheless exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several file you can check, after /etc/profile (it does some includes at the end too), /etc/bash.bashrc

- /etc/bashrc
- ~/.profile
- ~/.bash_profile
- ~/.bashrc

The order in which this files are read (if the exist) is specified in the bash manpage in the section INVOCATION.